# UICollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems not working for some case

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with each page be the exactly same size as the screen. The scroll direction is horizontal. I want to get the current visible cells while the view is scrolling.

For example, if i'm on one whole page, I just get this page's index, if I'm scrolling in the middle of two pages, then I can get these two pages index. I know there is `indexPathsForVisibleItems` method. It works for the case when scrolling in the middle. It will return two cells' index.

But if I'm on a whole page, it will return two pages as well. More strange, this happens on my iPhone 7 Plus, but when I test it on iPhone 6s, it works fine and return the current page's single index.

Seems the method doesn't work for larger screens?

My collection view:

```
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].fixedBounds.size;
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0;
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0;
    flowLayout.itemSize = screenSize;

    UIColloctionView *collectionView =
        [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:SCRectMakeWithSize(screenSize) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    collectionView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

The method i used to get current visible index:

```
    NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *indexPaths = [_tabsCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
```

On larger screen, this will return 2 items when I'm viewing the whole page.

Comment: Some related code will be helpful.

Comment: I don't know about your issue, but another work around could be to check the scroll offset to retrieve the indexPath. It's easier if have only one section, multiples rows, or one row per sections.

Answer (score 5):

Even I was facing the similar type of issue.

The workaround that has worked for me is below

**Swift 3** **Solution**

```
    var visibleRect    = CGRect()
    visibleRect.origin = collectionView.contentOffset
    visibleRect.size   = collectionView.bounds.size
    let visiblePoint   = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)

    guard let visibleIndexPath: IndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) else { return }
    print(visibleIndexPath)
```

Hope this solution works for you.